# Scripting process names with spaces when using TASKLIST command in a bat file

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2, tasklist

I'm trying to run a bat file that has a TASKLIST command for a process with a space in the name.  I'm using the following code:

```
set "exe=The Process.exe"
tasklist /FI "PROCESSES eq %exe%"
...
```

but it returns

```
C:\folder>set "exe=The Process.exe"
C:\folder>tasklist /FI "PROCESSES eq The Process.exe"
ERROR: The search filter cannot be recognized.
```

So how do I go about running a tasklist command in a bat file for a process with a space in the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have used an invalid keyword in your tasklist filter - `PROCESSES` should be `IMAGENAME`.

```
set "exe=The Process.exe"
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %exe%"
...
```

For more filters, take a look at the help for the tasklist command - `tasklist /?`

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I was also doing a wmic and using "process" in there, too, so I guess I got mixed up.  Thanks!